# Read a log file and find specific details

Tags: python-2.7, logfile

I have a log file, in .txt format

Now I have to find the log entry between specific time frames using python.

I tried using iteration and range.

So Please any suggestion is accepted.

Log file looks like this :

> 2015-12-15 00:51:01,904 INFO restserver.py 113
>   v........................ and so on

so find the log entry only with certain time frame.

Comment: Post the snippet of code you had made & also data of the txt file.

Comment: Your question is unclear as we don't know what format your data is in. Please provide sample input and what your requested output should look like in this case.

Comment: Still lacking details. How about put some extra sample lines and show us how you want to search using the time frame? Show the expected result for one situation, at least.

Comment: 2015-12-15 03:00:00 to 2015-12-15 03:59:00. That's the time limit. I want all the available log entry between that time frame

Comment: Do you have tried anything? If yes, please post the code.

Answer (score 0):

If you read your whole log file into a string, then you may use this :

```
import re
str = '2015-12-15 00:51:01,904 INFO restserver.py 113 .... 2015-12-16 00:51:01,904 INFO restserver.py 114 ....'
date1="2015-12-15 00:51:01"
date2="2015-12-16 00:51:01"
result = re.search(date1+'(.*)'+date2, str)
print result.group(1)
```

> Output : **,904 INFO restserver.py 113 ....**

Edited code for use case(by OP):

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python
 #Import the regular expression
 import re
 #Set the begining time and name it as starttime
 starttime="03:00:00"
 #Set the ending time and name it as endtime
 endtime="03:59:59"
 #Specify the time format
 time_re = re.compile(r'(\d+:\d+:\d+)')
 #Using the condition with open("abc.log", "r") as fh:
 for line in fh.readlines():
    match = time_re.search(line)
    if match:
        matchDate = match.group(1)
        if matchDate >= starttime and matchDate <= endtime:
            print match.string.strip()
```

Comment: Thanks Ani Menon: I finally got it:The code is below  : #!/usr/bin/env python
#Import the regular expression
import re
#Set the begining time and name it as starttime
starttime="03:00:00"
#Set the ending time and name it as endtime
endtime="03:59:59"
#Specify the time format
time_re = re.compile(r'(\d+:\d+:\d+)')

#Using the condition
with open("abc.log", "r") as fh:
    for line in fh.readlines():
        match = time_re.search(line)
        if match:
           matchDate = match.group(1)
           if matchDate >= starttime and matchDate <= endtime:
               print match.string.strip()

Answer (score 0):

## !/usr/bin/env python

## Import the regular expression

import re

print "The task Begins"

print " The Begin time is at 03:00:00"

## Set the beginning time and name it as starttime

starttime="03:00:00"

print "The End time is at 03:59:59"

## Set the ending time and name it as endtime

endtime="03:59:59"

## Specify the time format

time_re = re.compile(r'(\d+:\d+:\d+)')

## Using the condition

with open("abc.log", "r") as fh:

```
    for line in fh.readlines():
        match = time_re.search(line)
        if match:
           matchDate = match.group(1)
           if matchDate >= starttime and matchDate <= endtime:
               print match.string.strip()
```

print "The task is completed"